# How is this elementary problem equivalent to the Riemann Hypothesis?

Tags: number-theory, riemann-hypothesis

The problem I'm referring to is: Lagarias' Elementary Version of the Riemann Hypothesis, which states:

> For a positive integer $n$, let $\sigma(n)$ be the sum of all of its
>   positive divisors. Let $H_n$ denote the $n$-th Harmonic number.
>   ($\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}$).
>
> Is the inequality true for all $n$ greater than or equal to $1$?
>
> $$\sigma(n)\leq H_n+\ln(H_n)e^{H_n}$$

I want to gain some insight as to how the problems are equivalent.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1897888/276986), you need to see how the Riemann hypothesis is related with the [prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem), and then to study the Robin/Nicolas/Lagarias papers.

Comment: That's not an equality, that's an inequality.

Comment: "seemingly simple problem": haha.

Comment: The interesting question is *why.* With this I want to do feedback from a different viewpoint trying a comparison with Prime Number Theorem. For each perfect number $m$ one can define a sequence $a_n(m)=\sum_{1<d\mid m}\frac{1}{d^n-1}$ depending on $m$, that satisfies  $\forall k\geq 1$, $a_k>0$, and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(n)a_n=1$ (using Lambert series). The second condition is equivalent to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n}(na_n+\log n)=0$. But I don't know how interpret it, thus don't ask me about it. With respect your question I would like encourage to you to read Lagarias paper. Thanks